# C++ eliminar y modificar un nodo de una lista recibido de un archivo binario

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lista, winapi

Tengo un programa en winapi pero me salta una excepcion al momento de querer eliminar un nodo de una lista doblemente ligada o modificarlo en el programa, esta lista se esta recibiendo de un archivo binario

```
case BTN_USUARIOSELIMINAR:
    {
        char nombre[50];
        GetDlgItemTextA(hDialogoActual, LBL_USERNOMBELIMINAR, nombre, 50);
        string snombre(nombre);

        auxEliminar = inicioListaUser;

        while (auxEliminar != nullptr)
        {
            if (snombre == auxEliminar->nombre) {
                eliminar = 1;
                break;
            }
            auxEliminar = auxEliminar->sig;
        }

        if (snombre == auxUs->nombre)
        {
            eliminar = 0;
            SetDlgItemTextA(hDialogoActual, LBL_ELIMINARAVISO, "No se puede eliminar usuario actual");
        }

        if (eliminar == 1)
        {
            auxEliminar = inicioListaUser;
            while (auxEliminar != nullptr && auxEliminar->nombre != snombre) {
                auxEliminar = auxEliminar->sig;
            }

            if (auxEliminar == nullptr)
            {
                SetDlgItemTextA(hDialogoActual, LBL_ELIMINARAVISO, "Necesita Seleccionar un Usuario");
            }

            else if (auxEliminar == inicioListaUser)
            {
                inicioListaUser = inicioListaUser->sig;
                if (inicioListaUser != nullptr) {
                    inicioListaUser->ant = nullptr;
                }
                else
                {
                    finListaUser = nullptr;
                }
                delete auxEliminar;
            }

            else if (auxEliminar == finListaUser)
            {
                finListaUser = finListaUser->ant;
                if (finListaUser != nullptr)
                {
                    finListaUser->sig = nullptr;
                }
                else {
                    inicioListaUser = nullptr;
                }
                delete auxEliminar;
            }

            else
            {
                auxEliminar->ant->sig = auxEliminar->sig;
                auxEliminar->sig->ant = auxEliminar->ant;
                delete auxEliminar;
            }

            int id = 1;
            auxUsM = inicioListaUser;
            while (auxUsM != NULL)
            {
                auxUsM->id = id++;
                auxUsM = auxUsM->sig;
            }
            SetDlgItemTextA(hDialogoActual, LBL_ELIMINARAVISO, "Usuario Eliminado");
        }

        else
        {
            SetDlgItemTextA(hDialogoActual, LBL_ELIMINARAVISO, "Necesita Seleccionar un Usuario");
        }
    }
    break;
```

Cabe recalcar que si funciona el agregar un nodo a la lista  y  tambien que cada puntero esta inicializado en null, la excepcion ocurre especificamente cuando se ejecuta el delete, funciona perfectamente con dummy data pero al tener la lista desde un binario ocurre la excepcion, si alguien puede encontrar algun error de logica o que le haya pasado algo similar me seria de mucha ayuda saberloi, gracias.

Comment: Sin un ejemplo e datos de entrada lo único que podemos hacer es adivinar lo que está pasando, y en ese caso es más eficiente que depures el programa en tu máquina. Hablando de eficiencia, no tienes necesidad de reinventar la rueda, si quieres guardar datos de usuario en una lista, puedes usar alguno de los contenedores estándar del lenguaje como `std::list`, te ahorrará este tipo de problemas.

Comment: El error podría estar en la rutina que lee el archivo. Si deja mal enlazada la lista, obviamente las operaciones sobre ella van a fallar.